# Auto-Loading Multiple Levels of Nested JSON in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, json, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am having an issue with loading JSON containing multiple levels of nesting.  I have a model (Location) which has a set of models (Items) associated with each.

**Item Model**

```
Ext.define('SenchaSandbox.model.Item', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: ['Ext.data.Field'],

    config: {
        fields: ['id', 'name']
    }
});
```

**Location Model**

```
Ext.define('SenchaSandbox.model.Location', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: ['Ext.data.Field', 'Ext.data.association.HasMany'],

    uses: ['SenchaSandbox.model.Item'],

    config: {
        fields: ['id', 'name'],
        associations: [{
            type: 'hasMany',
            model: 'SenchaSandbox.model.Item',
            autoLoad: true,
            name: 'items'
        }]
    }
});
```

**Location Store**

```
Ext.define('SenchaSandbox.store.LocationStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'Location',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    config: {
        model: 'SenchaSandbox.model.Location',
        storeId: 'LocationStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'DummyGood.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'location'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In an ideal world, if the JSON from the server looked like the following, Sencha would load the Location and it's associated Items automatically.

**Good JSON**

```
{"location": [
    {
        "id": 100,
        "name": "Location 1",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Item A"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Item B"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 200,
        "name": "Location 2",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Item A"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Item C"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

However, the server actually returns JSON with some additional nesting that looks like below.

**Bad (Server) JSON**

```
{"CollectionLocation": {
    "collection": [
        {
            "id": 100,
            "name": "Location 1",
            "items": {
                "collection": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Item A"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Item B"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Location 2",
            "items": {
                "collection": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Item A"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Item C"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
 }}
```

Assuming that I have no control over the server code that generates this JSON, what are my options for loading this data in a clean fashion? Can I still take advantage of Sencha's auto-load capabilities or would I need to write code myself that creates the child-store and populates it with the child models?

I have created a Fiddle here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7n6 in case anyone has a minute to mess around with the sample.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ext.data.TreeStore` instead of `Ext.data.Store`

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore